# Return array from foreach() loop and print_r() it

Tags: php, arrays

I am doing some study on arrays, and I am trying to resolve how to store the values of a `foreach` loop into an array which I can then `print_r()`.

My script works fine with the exception of the `$array = foreach()...` And as you can see I called `return;` to return the results to the `$array` variable, but I am getting a parse error.

Here is my code so far:

```
<?php

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
  <input type="radio" name="DataNameOne" value="Value 1">
  <input type="radio" name="DataNameTwo" value="Value 2">
  <input type="radio" name="DataNameThree" value="Value 3">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php

$array = foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    if (stristr($key, "section")) {
        $section = $value;
        $section_name = $key;
        return;
    }
    echo "Key is: $key and Valus is: $value";
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just do

```
$array = $_POST;
```

since $_POST is already an array. However if you want to use the foreach loop to iterate a source array and copy only certain parts of it, you'd do something like:

```
$new_array = array()
foreach($original_array as $key => $value) {
    if (...filter condition(s)...) {
        $new_array[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

There's also [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map), [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/preg_grep), etc... which you mangle/filter array as you please.

Comment: I way over complicated this one! I think the first thing I learned was $_POST was an array. Thanks for the tip and info resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I am really sorry this post was so confusing. My code was copied from a source and I've been changing the names and values around in the html and php to learn this..

I was over complicating the entire thing, and resolved it by:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    if (stristr($key, "section")) {
        $section = $value;
        $section_name = $key;
            return;
    }
    echo "Key is: $key and Valus is: $value";
}


echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_POST is array.if we use print_r($_POST); of above form, we find array:-
code:-
-------------

$data=array(); 
$new_array=array(); 
echo"<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
$data[]=$_POST['DataNameOne'];
$data[]=$_POST['DataNameTwo'];
$data[]=$_POST['DataNameThree'];
print_r($data);   
foreach($ as $key => $value) { 
          if (...filter condition(s)...) {  
           $new_array[$key]=$value;
         } }

output:-
-------------
Array
(
    [DataNameOne] => Value 1
    [DataNameTwo] => Value 2
    [DataNameThree] => Value 3
)

Array
(
    [0] => Value 1
    [1] => Value 2
    [2] => Value 3
)
```